# Cannot resolve 'mathjs/number'

Tags: mathjs

I am using Math.js to parse and evaluate a mathematical expression, and am following the example at https://mathjs.org/docs/custom_bundling.html#numbers-only as I only need basic number support.  `"mathjs": "^8.1.1",` is listed in my package.json dependencies.

When I run the example code below, I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mathjs/number'`:

```js
// use light-weight, numbers only implementations of functions
import { create, all } from 'mathjs/number'

const math = create(all)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like maybe the documentation hasn't caught up.  I was able to get this working by changing the line

```js
import { create, all } from 'mathjs/number';
```

to

```js
import { create, all } from 'mathjs/lib/esm/number';
```

Comment: Does this still work for you? It doesn't for me. (And I have the same initial issue that you had)

Comment: Essentially yes, we still use `^8.1.1` but now import individual dependencies. `import { create, evaluateDependencies, addDependencies, subtractDependencies, multiplyDependencies, divideDependencies, powDependencies, /* ... */ } from 'mathjs/lib/esm/number';`.  Then we do `const math = create({ addDependencies, subtractDependencies, multiplyDependencies, divideDependencies, powDependencies, /* ... */ });`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, neither works for me - I can't import from anything other than just straight-up "mathjs". You're not using TypeScript, by any chance? I'm suspecting the issue I have is arising from bad types linking or something.

Comment: Nope, vanilla JS